# Автоматически устанавливать полное имя для колонок в таблицах после JOIN

Tags: sql

Кажется такая проблема встречается не во всех SQL компиляторах, но в Snowflake она точно есть. После JOIN двух таблиц у результата имена колонок не содержат названия исходных таблиц и это рождает проблемы, например, при создании VIEW.

```
select * from t1 join t2 where t1.name = t2.name
```

Если в этом случае t1 и t2 содержат колонки с одинаковыми именами(а они содержат как минимум одно), то мы получаем таблицу с дублирующимися названиями колонок, т.е. в имени колоники не указывается откуда она взялась. Поэтому я не могу сделать VIEW и прочее.
Все советы, которые я нашел заключаются в том, чтобы дать псевдонимы колонкам, но я не могу это сделать, так как это универсальный запрос из Python-коннектора, я не знаю какие имена столбцов у меня в реальности будут. Неужели предлагается их парсить и как-то сложно собирать SQL запрос?
NATURAL JOIN не очень подходит, так как там должны совпадать все пересекающиеся колонки, а в моем случае это не так.

Comment: Sql очень простой язык. Каких-то ключевых слов для генерации псевдонимом нет. Если вас устроит значения из одной таблицы, то можно заменить звёздочку на t1.* или t2.*.

Comment: Я вот не видел ни одного SQL, который бы дописывал имена таблиц. Да и это было бы странно, ведь в запросе одна и та же таблица может быть много раз. А использование select * при работе более чем с одной таблицей вообще плохой тон, всегда надо перечислять то, что действительно нужно в результате. Если у вас такое генерит некий коннектор, то стоит задуматься, а зачем он вообще нужен

Comment: *встречается не во всех SQL компиляторах* SQL-компиляторов - не существует. *Если в этом случае t1 и t2 содержат колонки с одинаковыми именами(а они содержат как минимум одно), то мы получаем таблицу с дублирующимися названиями колонок, т.е. в имени колоники не указывается откуда она взялась.* Забота о различении - целиком и полностью забота автора SQL-кода. Неспособен перечислить требуемые поля, присвоив им уникальные алиасы? ССЗБ.

Comment: _то мы получаем таблицу с дублирующимися названиями колонок_. нет, все имена колонок в результате выборки уникальны. Вопрос в целом непонятен, поэтому привидите минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Если приведённый в вопросе пример это универсальный запрос из какого-то коннектора, то обратитесь к документации этого самого конектора.